# How to Kill a Bat file Windows that was run as admin?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I found a Spotify Premium Free for Windows which I downloaded, but one of the files
was a .bat file that was named "run as admin", which I did. It worked and removes
ads from the Spotify application, but how do I kill the process and revert it back?
I've tried many things, but I just am not experienced. I have pasted the contents 
of the .bat file below, thank you!

```
@ECHO OFF
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

TITLE=Spotify Hosts File CrackedForYou
copy C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.bck
ECHO. >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 pubads.g.doubleclick.net >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 securepubads.g.doubleclick.net >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 www.googletagservices.com >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 gads.pubmatic.com >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 ads.pubmatic.com >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO 0.0.0.0 spclient.wg.spotify.com >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
EXIT
```

Comment: All it did was add entries into your hosts file, which blocks the ads, you will need to manually edit the hosts file and remove them, you can google how to edit the hosts file found at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Please clarify what you did and what you want to do. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Moab when I go into drivers\etc there is no hosts file, in fact the etc folder is completely empty.. I might have accidentally tampered with it before, what should I do?

Comment: Its a hidden file, you will have to go to folder options>view tab in control panel and un tick the boxes to unhide them.

Comment: Thank you so much @Moab I thought it was a lost cause, but you have promptly solved my problem just like that. Thank you!

Comment: @Moab You should make your suggestion an answer so it can be accepted by the OP and make it easier for visitors to find.